# Like XMP facial tagging, is there a way to visually tag other areas of the image as non-facial... notes, other items?

Tags: metadata, tagging, xmp

I'm looking for a metadata solution.  My environment is Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/129/21

Comment: It seems to me that this is a different question.  It would be nice to have the original asker flesh out the details a bit more with some examples, but I'm guessing they're looking for things like tagging what area of the photo contains, say, an apple, or a boat, or some other arbitrary object.  And it sounds like they'd like to tag the geography of such object, not just that it's in the photo... which does mean the other answer may be provide a "no", even here.  :-/

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't tag an item the same way you'd tag a person? It'd just be a separate pool, but otherwise, most of the functionality I would envision useful for such a thing would be the same...

Comment: Not much more to flush out really.  lindes... Correct, I'm looking to tag objects, like people, in the photograph, identifying the coordinates of the object, but also support notes/descriptions to a specific region of the image, similar to flickr's implementation.  I am not looking for an external, sidecar implementation, rather an embedded standard that would hopefully be embraced by application developers.  Could I use facial tagging to do this?  Perhaps, but the definition is facial, so when I submit my image to a specific application it would think it is a person--which I do not want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having trouble finding a definitive answer to your question.  This may well be something that has yet to be properly addressed by the relevant standards bodies, and thus something you "can't do" (yet).

That said, here are some pointers to areas for further research.  I've investigated them somewhat (though in less detail than is possible, by a long shot), and will give notes on what I've found in each:

- http://metability.editme.com/mmf-scavenger-xmp-schemaex-MSPeopleTagging

  I got to this document by way of searches related to things I turned up in other documents, below -- It seems to be saying that the structure for tagging specific areas (or, in the terminology used here, "regions") of a photo is based on a standard from Microsoft that's specifically intended for tagging people.  Of course, this doesn't preclude there being some other standard to do what you want... just a data point.
- http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=1404.0

  Threads such as this one, showing the (partial) XML content of an XMP file, are how I found the search strings that got me to the above article.
- http://phoshare.googlecode.com/svn-history/r9/trunk/tilutil/exiftool.py

  A Python script which also gave some relevant information for strings to search for.
- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html

  Links to a whole bunch of technical documents (and SDK, etc.) about XMP.  In my skimming through a few of these documents, I had trouble finding anything that talked about region-based tagging (even of faces), though it's entirely possible that I was skipping over something because it used words different than what I was searching for.
- http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp/standards.html

  Another possible Adobe-based source for links to relevant things.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490552/how-to-display-and-tag-a-region-of-an-image-with-python

  A seemingly-related question on StackOverflow.
- http://www.cipa.jp/english/hyoujunka/kikaku/pdf/DC-008-2010_E.pdf

  EXIF specification document (perhaps EXIF could support it?  But I didn't find it there, either.)
- http://www.iptc.org/site/Home/

  The IPTC standard can be downloaded from here, another possible place to look -- though again, I didn't find it there.

Hopefully, this answer is somehow useful to you, and/or will help someone else find an even better answer.

In the mean time, perhaps filing a feature request with the software provider for whatever piece(s) of software you're using, will help drive the changes necessary to make this possible??

Because clearly, it'd be useful.  :)

And it *has* been done, in ways...  e.g.: One option is that the [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/) [API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) (and web user interface) offers a way to add "notes", which have specific regions associated with them.  If doing the tagging on flickr would be of use to you, then you might try that -- look at the [API docs](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) for the various calls that start with "flickr.photos.notes", or (depending on exactly what you're trying to do), just upload a picture, and then click-and-drag across it on its page, and it'll prompt you for adding a note.  There may be other programs, sites, etc. that have done this as well, I'm not sure.